# What WYSIWYG editor is Stack Overflow using?

Tags: support, editor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the difference between the wmd editor and the one hosted on github?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27821/whats-the-difference-between-the-wmd-editor-and-the-one-hosted-on-github)
>   [Where's the WMD editor open source project?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71822/wheres-the-wmd-editor-open-source-project)

I feel that the editor I'm using to input questions on Stack Overflow is a very smooth, comfortable and easy to use beast.

Is it a variety of CKEditor or developed from scratch?

If possible, I want use it in my own website.

Comment: It may be smooth, comfortable and easy to use, but WYSIWYG?

Comment: Indeed, the people behind WMD prefer to call it **Wysiwym** (What You See Is What You Mean): http://wmd-editor.com/

Comment: I've made my own alternative: http://blog.gauffin.org/2012/02/introducing-griffin-editor-a-jquery-textarea-plugin/ MPL licensed.

Comment: Links to wmd-editor.com look defunct, this might be the current link? http://code.google.com/p/wmd/

Comment: @Nanne http://code.google.com/p/pagedown/

Answer (score 10):

As mentioned in [this SO blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/12/reverse-engineering-the-wmd-editor/) it's the [WMD Markdown Editor](http://wmd-editor.com/)

Answer (score 1):

[WMD Editor](http://wmd-editor.com/).

Comment: Link no longer valid

Comment: The current editor is Stacks-Editor https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor