# What's the difference between the wmd editor and the one hosted on github?

Tags: support, editor

Bit confused, what is the difference between the version of the editor on Github and the one here: http://wmd-editor.com/

Is it the same thing?

Answer (score 19):

The WMD editor story goes something like this:

Jeff and team started with the original WMD code at http://wmd-editor.com and it was written by a chap called John Fraser. There's an early blog article about choosing WMD as the code/text editor here:

> [Potential Markup and Editing Choices (blog.stackoverflow.com)](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/05/potential-markup-and-editing-choices/)

For reasons only known to himself, John became uncontactable so Jeff & Co decided to reverse engineer the code because the only release available was obfuscated/minified and a number of fixes/enhancements were required:

> [Reverse Engineering the WMD Editor (blog.stackoverflow.com)](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/12/reverse-engineering-the-wmd-editor/)

The fruits of their labours culminated in a version that is now hosted on GitHub:

> [WMD Editor Reverse Engineered (blog.stackoverflow.com)](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/wmd-editor-reverse-engineered/)
>
> [Updated WMD Editor (blog.stackoverflow.com)](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/updated-wmd-editor/)

The code on GitHub (http://github.com/cky/wmd) was the code being used by the Stack Overflow family of sites. From there it moved to Google Code:

> http://code.google.com/p/wmd-new/

The original WMD code on Google Code (http://code.google.com/p/wmd/) seems to be pretty much dead-ended for now.

After a complete refactor, since August 2011 it's now released under a new name and is available on

> http://code.google.com/p/pagedown/

Comment: That's quite a beautiful story.

Comment: And they all lived happily ever after :)

Comment: @Kev not quite so soon, I suppose...

Comment: @Kev, I think this answer needs updating no? It seems that the google code repository is the active version of the editor now, no?

Comment: @mohamad - I guess you're right. Feel free to update :)

Comment: Wish I could up-vote this more!

Answer (score 0):

[The most active branch](http://github.com/ananthakumaran/wmd/)
[v2 download page](http://github.com/ananthakumaran/wmd/downloads)