# Wanted Stack Exchange's Markdown editor for github.com/slack.com

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, editor, github, userscript

I would like to have the same WYSIWYG markdown editor as the one on Stack Exchange's websites.

[image: http://pix.toile-libre.org/upload/original/1452122288.png]

The most wanted feature is the keyboard shortcuts like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> to add *backticks* around selection, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> to make links and so on. I'm pretty sure that will interest many people using GitHub all the day long.

I saw the post from 2008 (yes, it's far now) from Jeff Atwood itself explaining that [Stack Exchange websites use WMD editor](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/12/reverse-engineering-the-wmd-editor/).

As seen [there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/27842/203970), the project becomes [pagedown](http://samwillis.co.uk/pagedown-bootstrap/demo/browser/demo.html), but I don't know how to use it in a browser (Firefox at least) for a known list of websites. (It's super easy for a owned web site to integrate the library, but what about in a [greasemonkey](/questions/tagged/greasemonkey) script to enable it where we want?)

As a workaround usable on [Firefox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/firefox), I can use the external editor [stackedit](https://stackedit.io/) to open the `textarea`, but I prefer to have the editor directly in the web page. And as related [there](https://aur4.archlinux.org/packages/stackedit/), `StackEdit` connects to Google Analytics, [Google Drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Drive), [Dropbox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dropbox_%28service%29), [Bitly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitly), [WordPress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordPress), [Tumblr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tumblr) and probably some other ones.

Comment: It's all [here](https://github.com/maniator/pagedown/) as far as I can see.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Balpha's copy is at https://github.com/balpha/pagedown/, to eventually be moved to live under the SE org on Github. I don't know who maniator is, but just be aware that that version of the code might not be entirely up to date going forward.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying @Adam, for some reason when I searched I landed on that page - don't remember my exact search route though. maniator appears to be [this user](http://stackexchange.com/users/271284/neal), if it matters.

Comment: Nitpick: that isn't a WYSIWYG editor at all! It's a plaintext Markdown editor with keyboard shortcuts and a preview pane.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I said, the most wanted feature is the keyboard shortcuts. I wrote a userscript tested both on firefox 43.0.1 (need [greasemonkey](/questions/tagged/greasemonkey) addon) and chromium Version 47.0.2526.106 (need [tampermonkey](/questions/tagged/tampermonkey) addon).

Enabled sites :

- `https://*.slack.com/*`
- `https://github.com/*`
- `https://gist.github.com/*`

Enabled keyboard shortcuts :

- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> : **bold**
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> : *emphasis*
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> : `code`
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd> : [link](http://nowhere.null)

https://gist.github.com/c6cbcc061d8257cbbd67

````js
// ==UserScript==
// @name        SO_like_keyboards_shortcuts
// @namespace   sputnick
// @include     https://github.com/*
// @include     https://gist.github.com/*
// @include     https://*.slack.com/*
// @include     https://stackoverflow.com/*
// @include     hhttps://serverfault.com/*
// @include     https://*stackexchange.com/*
// @include     https://askubuntu.com/*
// @include     https://superuser.com/*

// @version     1
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

// http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/272565/203970
// TODO need to work with gist

var id, name;
if (document.location.href.search(/gist\.github\.com/) > 0 ) { //TODO to be fixed
    id = '#blob_contents';
    name = 'gist';
}
else if (document.location.href.search(/github\.com.*new$/) > 0 ) {
    id = '#issue_body';
    name = 'github';
}
else if (document.location.href.search(/github\.com\/.*\/issues\/[0-9]+/) > 0 ) {
    id = '#new_comment_field';
    name = 'github';
}
else if (document.location.href.search(/slack\.com/) > 0 ) {
    id = '#message-input';
    name = 'slack';
}
else if (document.location.href.search(/(stackoverflow|stackexchange|superuser|askubuntu|serverfault)/) > 0 ) {
    id = '[id^=wmd-input]';
    name = 'stack';
}

(function() {
    document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
        //window.alert(e.which);

        if (document.activeElement.tagName == "TEXTAREA") {
            // ctrl+0 [tag:]
            if (e.ctrlKey && e.which == 96) {
                override(e);
                wrapText(id, '[tag:', ']');
            }
            // ctrl+b: bold
            if (e.ctrlKey && e.which == 66) {
                override(e);
                if (name == 'slack') { wrapText(id, '*', '*'); }
                if (name == 'github' || name == 'gist') { wrapText(id, '**', '**'); }
            }
            // ctrl+i: emphasis
            if (e.ctrlKey && e.which == 73) {
                override(e);
                wrapText(id, '_', '_');
            }
            // ctrl+k: code
            if (e.ctrlKey && e.which == 75) {
                override(e);
                wrapText(id, '`', '`');
            }
            // ctrl+l: link
            if (name !== 'stack' && e.ctrlKey && e.which == 76) {
                override(e);
                var p = window.prompt("Link paste bellow");
                wrapText(id, '[', ']('+p+')');
            }
        }
    }, true);
})();

function wrapText(elementID, openTag, closeTag) {
    var textArea = document.querySelector(elementID);
    var len = textArea.value.length;
    var start = textArea.selectionStart;
    var end = textArea.selectionEnd;
    var selectedText = textArea.value.substring(start, end);
    if (openTag == '`' && selectedText.search(/\n/) > 0 ) {
        openTag = '```\n';
        closeTag = '\n```';
    }
    var replacement = openTag + selectedText + closeTag;
    textArea.value = textArea.value.substring(0, start) + replacement + textArea.value.substring(end, len);
}

function override(e) {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    e.cancelBubble = true;
    e.preventDefault();
}
````

Comment: Updated code from post and gist

Answer (score 5):

I don't think this is really at all possible. I guess you could do a user script to override GitHub's editor with PageDown... but our markdown flavor isn't entirely compatible with GitHub's Markdown, so you'd be shooting yourself in the foot if you did so.

It's even worse for Slack:

> We're aware that some users would like to see enhanced Markdown options, but we don’t currently plan to support Markdown in Slack messages.

In other words, at the end of the day, the editor we have is suitable for hosting on a website, but it's not designed or intended to be a browser extension that is usable on *other* sites.

Comment: For slack, I'm just interested for the beyboard shortcut `ctrl+k` to format code. I guess that I should implement my own userscript using by example http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/ (I don't care about the buttons)